# How to discover table properties from SQLAlchemy mapped object

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, instrumentation

I have a class mapped with a table, in my case in a declarative way, and I want to "discover" table properties, columns, names, relations, from this class:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///' + databasePath, echo=True)

# setting up root class for declarative declaration
Base = declarative_base(bind=engine)

class Ship(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ships'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255))

    def __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
            return "<Ship('%s')>" % (self.name)
```

So now my goal is from the "Ship" class to get the table columns and their properties from another piece of code. I guess I can deal with it using instrumentation but is there any way provided by the SQLAlchemy API?

Comment: See also the related question at http://stackoverflow.com/q/2537471/25507

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Information you need you can get from [Table](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table) object:

- `Ship.__table__.columns` will provide you with columns information
- `Ship.__table__.foreign_keys` will list foreign keys
- `Ship.__table__.constraints`, `Ship.__table__.indexes` are other properties you might find useful

Comment: Is there a way to get attributes declared using `@declared_attr` in base classes in the body of the class itself? I would like to declare column using sequence with the name of sequence created based on table's name which is itself defined in a base class using `@declared_attr`.

Answer (score 0):

If declarative base is not used, the answer fails. The following should work no matter how it's initialized

For Class Object:

```
TableClass.sa_class_manager.mapper.mapped_table.name
```

For Instance Object:

```
tableObj.sa_instance_state.mapper.mapped_table.name
```

Comment: Do not forget underscore in the `_sa_instance_state`