# Get Table Name By Table Class In Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to pass a class to a function, and don't like to pass the name again.

```
class TableClass(Base):
    __table__ = Table('t1', metadata, autoload=True)
def get_name(TableClass):
    print TableClass.GetTableName()  # print 't1'
get_name(TableClass)
```

So, I search it with google, and there is no answer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

According To:

[How to discover table properties from SQLAlchemy mapped object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441796/how-to-discover-table-properties-from-sqlalchemy-mapped-object)

I can use this:

```
print TableClass.__table__.name
```

Answer (score 6):

Independent on whether you use declarative extension or not, you can use the [Runtime Inspection API](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/inspection.html):

```
def get_name(TableClass):
    from sqlalchemy import inspect
    mapper = inspect(TableClass)
    print mapper.tables[0].name
```

Please note that a class can have multiple tables mapped to it, for example when using [Inheritance](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/inheritance.html).

Answer (score 5):

```
print TableClass.__tablename__
```

works for me

Comment: This won't work if you need table name in string since it will return 
<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.schema.Table'>  use str((cls.__table__.name))) instead.

Answer (score 1):

In SQLAlchemy you can fetch table information with tableclass attributes.

In your example

<strike>`print TableClass.__tablename__  # Prints 't1'`</strike>

According to @Aylwyn Lake 's Finding

```
print TableClass.__table__.name
```

Comment: `type object 'TableClass' has no attribute '__tablename__'`

Comment: Yeah You are right. But it will work when you create Table Class using Base Class. As mentioned [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html#declare-a-mapping)

Comment: This assumes that the user is mapping using the `__tablename__` attribute when setting up their code, which while is sometimes the case, is not how the code in the question is set up.

Comment: @MarkHildreth: Than't right. So there are two methods of creating Table Class: one is `__table__`; the other is `__tablename__`

Answer (score 1):

I just hit this issue myself, passing the object around and didn't want to pass the string of the tablename as well..

Turns out, it's just a property of the Table object, eg:

```py
table = new Table("somename",meta)

...
print("My table is called: " + table.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers worked for me.

This did:

For Class Object:

```
TableClass.sa_class_manager.mapper.mapped_table.name
```

For Instance Object:

```
tableObj.sa_instance_state.mapper.mapped_table.name
```