# Get custom attributes of a class Python

Tags: python, class, attr

Is it possible to get the name of our custom attributes of a class in Python ? For instance, here's my class :

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    login = db.Column(db.String(100))
    password = db.Column(db.String(100))
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    email = db.Column(db.String(100))
    age = db.Column(db.Integer)
    sex = db.Column(db.String(10))
```

What I want is to get the list of my class attributes (and only those that I defined !). I was thinking about using `dir(self)` and filtering on those not starting with `__` but it's not really revelant because there are other fields who are built-in such as `metadata`, `query` and so on.

I saw a function `getattr (or getattribute)` but it's only for a given field.

I don't want to use a dict of keys because it have to stay generic and I don't want to modify the dict everytime I add a field.

As I'm using `SqlAlchemy ORM`, I got this when trying `self.__dict__` :

```
 {'_sa_instance_state': <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState object at 0x7ffbcf252050>}
```

I also tried a lot of things such as those described here :
[Python dictionary from an object's fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61517/python-dictionary-from-an-objects-fields) but nothing worked.

Does anyone have a solution ?

Thanks !

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441796/how-to-discover-table-properties-from-sqlalchemy-mapped-object/2448930#2448930

Comment: I am looking for the same thing in python3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting attributes of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058305/getting-attributes-of-a-class)